# how to add something to an object if it doesn't have it already

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Dealing with ES6, I have an object and I need to add something to it if it already doesn't have it, so below is my work:

```
const a = {name:"haha",address:"here",rate:6};
const b = {rate:3,...a};
```

so if object `a` has that `rate` it will remain but if it doesn't have it, `rate:3` will be added to the object. BUT, I remember that we could do it with `||` operator (or `&&`, I don't remember which operator). could you tell me how it was done that way?

Comment: `rate: a.rate || 3`? But probably better to test for `undefined` explicitly, otherwise `0` and other falsey values won't pass

Comment: @CertainPerformance  thanks, could you add that `undefined` testing part and post this as an answer? thanks

Comment: `'rate' in a && (a.rate = 3);` if the separate object b is not needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the keyword `in` to check if the property exists

```
b.rate = 'rate' in b ? a.rate : 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The "old" way to do it would be:

```
b.rate = a.rate || 3; // This would fail if a.rate === 0
b.rate = a.rate === undefined ? 3 : a.rate; // This would fail if a.rate === null
b.rate = a.rate === undefined || a.rate === null ? 3 : a.rate;
```

You could also use `Object.assign` to simulate object-spread:

```
const b = Object.assign({rate: 3}, a);
```

Comment: The last one could just be `Object.assign({rate: 3}, a);`.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, but it's usually recommended to start with an empty object to avoid bugs

Comment: @farmcommand edited to add the corner cases, but then it becomes a bit cumbersome... I would default to `Object.assign` if you don't have support for object-spread, or a constructor function

Comment: @SrThompson: What kind of bugs? Sure, if you don't want to mutate the original object you have to make a shallow copy, which is achieved by passing an empty object, but since you are already passing a new object as second argument there is no need for that. You are just creating an unnecessary object.

Comment: @FelixKling good point, I guess it's just the force of habit. I'll edit that out

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a value with || by using:

```
const val = something || somethingElse;
```

However, this doesn't work as well when using it for objects. E.g

```
const obj1 = { rate: 1 };
obj1.rate = obj1.rate || 1; // this is fine
obj1.rate = obj1.rate || obj2.rate; // if obj1.rate and obj2.rate do not exist, obj1.rate will be set to undefined. But that's not always what you want. If you don't want rate set at all, this would be an unexpected result
```

Answer (score 0):

Before object spread was usable, you could use:

```js
const a = {name:"haha",address:"here",rate:6};
const b = Object.assign({}, a, { rate: a.rate || 3 });
console.log(b);
```

But this may not work as intended, because using `||` relies on the preceding expression being *truthy*. If `a.rate` is falsey but still defined, like the empty string or `0`, then it will be overwritten, so it may be better to avoid `||` and explicitly check for whether `a.rate` is defined or not, which can be put into the `rate` property concisely with the conditional operator:

```js
const a = {name:"haha",address:"here",rate:6};
const b = Object.assign({}, a, {
  rate: a.rate === undefined ? 3 : a.rate
});
console.log(b);
```